# How would the pole and zero frequency expression look like for this transfer function I derived?

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, bode-plot, laplace-transform

This is a practice problem in deriving the transition frequency function for mos and part of the set of questions is to determine the pole and zero frequency expression but this transfer function i derived is kinda different from what i'm used to from  the previous lectures. I usually see this form:
[image]

But my derived transfer function looks a little different.

[image]

Could somebody guide me how to derive them?

Comment: By reading your i_0/i_i expression I though that gap between C_g d and C_g s meant they were different variables/parameters and read it as \$ G(s) = \frac{g_m -s C_g d}{s(C_g s+C_g d)} \$

Comment: Factor out the coefficients of \$s\$. For example, \$C_g\$ in the denominator.

Comment: If you're referring to the s term in the denominator, let \$P_1=0\$

Comment: @jDAQ sorry about that, my handwriting does suck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely in the generic transfer function, the \$s\$ operator is single, everywhere, and there is a gain parameter. So try to isolate those from your t.f.:

$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{g_m-sC_{gd}}{s(C_{gs}+C_{gd})}=\dfrac{-C_{gd}\left(s-\dfrac{g_m}{C_{gd}}\right)}{(C_{gd}+C_{gs})\left(s-\dfrac{0}{C_{gd}+C_{gs}}\right)}=-\dfrac{C_{gd}}{C_{gd}+C_{gs}}\dfrac{s-\dfrac{g_m}{C_{gd}}}{s-0}
\end{align}$$

Which is a pure integrator -- that makes sense, since you have no resistive elements, only capacitors and a current source. Notice the denominator now shows the zero valued pole (as mentioned by [Chu](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/536909/how-would-the-pole-and-zero-frequency-expression-look-like-for-this-transfer-fun#comment1389145_536909)).

Comment: whats a zero valued pole and how does it relate to an  integrator? Is that the same as a pole at the origin?

Comment: Yes. Pole at origin.

Comment: Is it right that the zero frequency = -Cgd/gm and the pole frequency = Cgd + Cgs? Because we had a graded exercise based on this and when i used zero freq to be -Cgd/gm, i got it wrong, also pole freq = 1/Cgd+Cgs is also wring which i dont understand.

Comment: @Rein Try to compare the last part of the formula above with your generic transfer function: \$\small{A}\frac{s-z}{s-p}\$. What similarities do you see? Which one can be \$z\$, which one \$p\$, and which one \$A\$?

Comment: Thanks Chu! I actually figured things out and got perfect scores!